# Why are Eigen Matrix Library's fixed size types with integral data not PoD?

Tags: c++, eigen

Given an Eigen fixed size type, say an Eigen::Vector3d, why is the type not PoD? The underlying data is an array of 3 doubles, and there should not be a need for a nontrivial constructor or destructor.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: @BaummitAugen std::copy can safely optimize to memcpy if Eigen::Vector3d is PoD (for example, with a std::vector of Eigen::Vector3ds).

Comment: The compiler can see what members it has and what the copy constructor does, so have you checked if your code did not get optimized as it should be?

Comment: Yes, which is how we identified the issue. An older custom library with a PoD Vec3 type was getting memcopied, Eigen is not. This is with Intel's compiler, we have not tested with GCC or Clang.

Comment: Welp, gcc and clang use a loop too. So I guess that's indeed something to complain about.

Answer (score 2):

Template wise, a  <s>lot</s> bit (depends on the version) goes on in the constructor, albeit at compile time. While all of this is evaluated at compile time and therefore optimized out, there is still a remaining empty constructor. If you add an empty constructor to a POD type, it too will not be memcpy'ed when using `std::copy`. Try this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct notpod
{
    notpod() {}
    double d[3];
};

struct pod
{
    double d[3];
};

using Eigen::Vector3d;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock > start, end;
    int sz = 20000000;

    {
        std::vector<pod> a(sz), b(sz);
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock ::now();
        std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock ::now();
        std::cout << "     POD vector copy took " << (std::chrono::duration<double>(end - start)).count() << " seconds.\n";
    }

    {
        std::vector<notpod> na(sz), nb(sz);
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock ::now();
        std::copy(na.begin(), na.end(), nb.begin());
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock ::now();
        std::cout << "  NotPOD vector copy took " << (std::chrono::duration<double>(end - start)).count() << " seconds.\n";
    }

    {
        std::vector<Vector3d> a3(sz), b3(sz);
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock ::now();
        std::copy(a3.begin(), a3.end(), b3.begin());
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock ::now();
        std::cout << "Vector3d vector copy took " << (std::chrono::duration<double>(end - start)).count() << " seconds.\n";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

which outputs on my machine:

> POD vector copy took 0.135008 seconds.
>     NotPOD vector copy took 0.35202 seconds.
>   Vector3d vector copy took 0.35302 seconds.